# Render cylinder tube along 3D Path

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm working on a roller coaster game, and I have computed a function that represents the path of the track in the 3D space. Since the track will be tubular and will be dynamically generated(as opposed to a very large obj file), I was wondering if there was any elegant way to render something like this.

Something like this is what I'm aiming for

[image]

PS: I'm currently working in SceneKit on iOS/OSX

Comment: I'm curious to know if anyone can come up with a tessellation solution. Depending on the platform, you could possibly send tube "paths" as a series of points and let the gpu calculate the rest in a geometry shader? This might be efficient, but rather complex to learn.  Reader further though, I doubt iOS will support that method.

Comment: I'm thinking of simplifying the tracks to simple cylinders and Spheres and/or using SCNShape
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShape_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNShape/path

Comment: Wait, is this an example of path controlled extrusion?